# Xamarin: How to recycle bitmap created by NGraphics

Tags: image, xamarin, graphic, recycle

I am having out of memory while loading an image to draw on a custom view via onDraw. I am using NGraphics but I can't see the IImage has a function call recycle or dispose the bitmap. So how do I proper destroy the object.

Comment: If you are using `IImage.LoadImage`, it returns a `BitmapImage` which has a `BitmapImage.Bitmap` property that returns a `Bitmap`. So you could call Dispose on that object, then `null` the `IImage` and call GC.Collect to force a clean up.... (This is from top of my head, results may vary)

Comment: I used null and GC ... feel like it does the trick .